# How do I get this input statement within an if statement to prompt while needing to use the variable outside of the scope?

Tags: python-3.x

So I want to prompt the user to input either a number 1-3 for a soda, 4 (or any other number) for water. If they select a soda, it should ask them for a size. If they select water however, it should skip the size question. I could turn the size question into an if statement if they select water, but then I can't use the size variable outside of this scope. How would I go about doing this? What I have right now prompts the size question for the water though all the calculations are correct.

```
HAMBURGER = 3.25
CHEESEBURGER = 3.25
CHICKEN = 2.50
SMALL = 1.50
MED = 2.25
LARGE = 2.75
WATER = 0.00
SALES_TAX = 0.08


sandwich = int(input("Sandwich?\nPlease 
enter 1 for a hamburger, 2 for a cheeseburger, 3 for a chicken sandwich 
or 4 for no sandwich: "))
if sandwich == 1:
    sandwich = HAMBURGER
elif sandwich == 2:
    sandwich = CHEESEBURGER
elif sandwich == 3:
    sandwich = CHICKEN
else:
    sandwich == 0

drink = float(input("Drink?\nPlease enter 1 for Coke, 2 for Sprite, 3 
for lemonade, or 4 for a cup of water: "))
water = drink < 1 or drink >= 4
size = float(input("Size?\nPlease enter 1 for Small, 2 for Medium, or 3 
for large: "))
if size == 1:
    size = SMALL
elif size == 2:
    size = MED
elif size == 3:
    size = LARGE
else:
    size = MED
if water:
    size = WATER

subtotal = (sandwich+(drink * size))
sales_tax = (subtotal * SALES_TAX)
total = (subtotal + sales_tax)

print("Here is your order: ")

if sandwich == HAMBURGER:
    print(f"Hamburger\t\t\t${HAMBURGER:10.2f}")
elif sandwich == CHEESEBURGER:
    print(f"Cheeseburger\t\t\t${CHEESEBURGER:10.2f}")
elif sandwich == CHICKEN:
    print(f"Chicken Sandwich\t\t\t${CHICKEN:<40.2f}")

if size == SMALL:
    print(f"Small Drink\t\t\t${SMALL:10.2f}")
if size == MED:
    print(f"Medium Drink\t\t\t${MED:10.2f}")
if size == LARGE:
    print(f"Large Drink\t\t\t${LARGE:10.2f}")
else:
    print(f"Water\t\t\t${WATER:<40.2f}")

print('-' * 30)
print(f"Subtotal: ${subtotal:.2f}")
print(f"Sales Tax: ${sales_tax:.2f}")
print(f"Total:  ${total:.2f}")
```

Comment: You could just move `if water: size=WATER` to before the prompt. Then have an `else:` to ask for the size. You can then include the various size if/elif statements in this else to avoid running through these when you already know its water.

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

You could check if water has been selected or not, if it hasn't ask for the size option.

```py
if water:
    size = WATER
else:
    size_option = input("Size?\nPlease enter 1 for Small, 2 for Medium, or 3 for large: ")
    if size_option == "1":
        size = SMALL
    elif size_option == "2":
        size = MED
    elif size_option == "3":
        size = LARGE
    else:
        size = MED
```

Comment: Thank you!! Also just another question. In the print statements for the sandwiches and drink, how do I get the number values to align? Right now the cost of the sandwich prints out more to the right than the drink cost.

Comment: That should probably be another question, and I think it might come after you've fixed the code to show the correct results - see what happens if you select a 'cheeseburger'.